# Is cache always reinitialized when the verification input is changed in light mode of rx

Tags: mining-technical-details

Is cache always reinitialized when verification input is changed in light mode of RX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is cache always reinitialized when verification input is changed in light mode of RX

You reinitialize the cache when the *seed hash* changes (which on Monero is every 2048 blocks).

Comment: how to find the block height when the key is going to change

Comment: `floor((height-lag-1)/2048)*2048` (here `height` is the *current* height and `lag` is 64), gets you the *current* seed height, and so `+2048+lag+1` is the next seed height change.